# Detect changes in element by multiple event

Tags: javascript, jquery

We can determine if the input changes by using code below

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#input1', function(event) 
{
    console.log('changes made');
});
```

But I have a lot of event that changes the value of **#input1**

for example

```
$(document).on('click', '#button1', function(event) 
{
    $("#input1").val("one");
});
```

Is there a way to detect the changes made on **#input1** without calling a function like

```
function inputIsChange()
{
   console.log('changes made');
}
```

Comment: well what you want to do??

Comment: something like this, but it is not working on me

$('mydiv').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  alert('changed');
});

Answer (score 1):

For input element you van use `input` event. `input` event occurs when the text content of an element is changed through the user interface.

```js
$(document).on('input', '#input1', function(event) 
{
    console.log('changes made');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1" />
```

Comment: How about if other element change the value of #input1?

Answer (score 0):

For input elements you can also use `.change`:

```
$('#input').change(function () {
     console.log('change detected');
});
```

Documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```js
$(document).on('input', '#input1', function() {
  console.log('Changes made');
});

$.fn.changeVal = function (value) {
  return this.val(value).trigger('input');
}
$('#input1').changeVal(12324324);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new method to handle the changes and then trigger your customEvent.

See my example below.

---

**Updated:**

Add event data.

```js
$(function () {
  function setNewValue(target, newData) {  
    $(target).html(newData); // <== html() || text() || val()
    $(target).trigger('customEvent');
  }
  
  $('button').on('click', function(e) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000) + 1;
    setNewValue($('#myDiv'), randomNumber);
  });
  
  $('#myDiv').on('customEvent', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv">test</div>

<button>click me</button>
```